# Configuring Gradle for Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-security

I've encountered a stack error while trying to create an example app to understand OAuth2. I'm using Google's OAuth2 server. The stack error was found when deploying to Heroku crashed and I checked the logs. There's another stack error that I found when running gradle test locally. I believe they are simply the same error.

This is the Heroku stack error

```
2018-05-27T03:01:33.075084+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-05-27 03:01:33.074  WARN 4 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.alexjamesmalcolm.persistmebaby.PersistMeBabyApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration due to org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723561+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-05-27 03:01:33.722 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723574+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723579+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.alexjamesmalcolm.persistmebaby.PersistMeBabyApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration due to org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723581+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:618) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723583+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:301) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723585+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:247) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723586+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:200) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723588+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:169) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723590+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723591+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723593+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723595+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723596+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723598+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723599+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.12.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723601+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.12.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723603+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.12.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723604+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.12.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723606+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.12.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723607+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.12.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723609+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.alexjamesmalcolm.persistmebaby.PersistMeBabyApplication.main(PersistMeBabyApplication.java:12) [classes!/:na]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723610+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723612+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723621+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723623+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723624+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [persist-me-baby-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723626+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [persist-me-baby-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723627+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [persist-me-baby-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723629+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [persist-me-baby-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723631+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration due to org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723632+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.12.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723634+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723635+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:219) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723637+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:608) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723639+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 25 common frames omitted
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723640+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723642+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2SsoCondition.getMatchOutcome(EnableOAuth2SsoCondition.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.12.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723644+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration$NeedsWebSecurityCondition.getMatchOutcome(OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration.java:82) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.12.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723645+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.12.RELEASE]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723647+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 28 common frames omitted
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723648+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723649+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723651+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723652+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[persist-me-baby-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723654+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171-heroku]
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723655+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 31 common frames omitted
2018-05-27T03:01:33.723657+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

And this is the gradle test stack error for contextLoads (the default test that comes with Spring initialzr)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.alexjamesmalcolm.persistmebaby.PersistMeBabyApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration due to org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:618)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:301)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration due to org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:55)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:219)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:608)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2SsoCondition.getMatchOutcome(EnableOAuth2SsoCondition.java:42)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration$NeedsWebSecurityCondition.getMatchOutcome(OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 71 more
```

This is my `build.gradle`, I followed the configuration from https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_simple

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.12.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'overflow.stack.hello'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    environment "JDBC_DATABASE_URL", "jdbc:h2:~/test"
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testRuntime('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

This is my SpringBootApplication class

```
package overflow.stack.hello.persistmebaby;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class PersistMeBabyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PersistMeBabyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my `application.yml`. Its location is `src/main/resources/application.yml`

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: ${CLIENT_ID}
      clientSecret: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
      accessTokenUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      scope: profile email
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

Comment: It seems like you need to include the security starter as well `spring-boot-starter-security`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zakaria Amine suggested this was an issue with my dependencies. I solved this problem by making some additions to my `build.gradle`.

This was my dependencies before

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testRuntime('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

And here's my dependencies after

```
ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Edgware.SR3' // Ties in with the dependencyManagement block below
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security') //added dependency
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2') //added dependency
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security') //added dependency
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testRuntime('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test') //added dependency
}

// for finding dependencies
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```